# Running 16 processes on single jvm machine

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm using a 64 GB RAM & 24 core machine and allocated 32 GB to JVM. I wanted to run following processes :-

```
7 Kafka Brokers
3 instance of zookeeper 
Elastic Search 
Cassandra
Spark
MongoDB
Mysql
Kafka Manager
Node.js
```

& running 4-5 Spark Application on 5-6 executor with 1GB each simulatenously. The working of Spark jobs are as follows :-

```
1) 1 Spark job takes data from kafka and inserts into Cassandra
2) 1 Spark job takes data from another kafka topic and inserts into different Cassandra Table.
3) 2 Spark Job takes data from Cassandra, did some processing/analysis and writes data into their respective different cassandra table.
```

So, Sometimes my insertion application gets hang. It is taking around 500 records/second from Kafka. After running for sometime, It starts creating batches in queue and there is no error still processing time in Spark dashboard is increasing gradually.

I have used TOP to check CPU usage and found there is one process "0QrmJB" which is taking 1500+ CPU% usage and java is taking 200% usage.

What might be the issues ? I'm not able to analyse.Is it ok to run these many processes on single JVM machine? Thanks,

Comment: As a first step, I would suggest to run `top` in order to monitor memory consumption per process. Theoretically, you are running a lot of memory-intensive processes (Kafka, Spark, Elastic Search etc) and you will either need to use more hosts (better in terms of high availability) or add some more memory. But as I said, as a first step just run `top` and see how it goes.

Comment: There is 1 process "0QrmJB" which is taking 1468% of CPU. any idea what does that mean ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the whole output?

Comment: Yes, I have done.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the output for the first 5-6 entries?

Comment: You realize that running all brokers on 1 machine provides no availability guarantees? If it goes down, the whole cluster is offline. Either way, it looks like way too many processes for a single machine.

Comment: @MickaelMaison - Yes, actually someone else has created this architecture and I'm just a developer writing spark jobs and my jobs were getting hang/stuck and I was unable to find out whats going wrong so wanted to know if running too many processes on single machine is good or not. Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: `I was unable to find out whats going wrong so wanted to know if running too many processes on single machine is good or not` for one thing the JVM will default to using all cores for GCs, if your running a bunch of competing java processes they will likely over saturate your system in simple GCs unless tuned.